# Php how to use multiple parameters

Tags: php

there are two parameters in my app, user will fill one of them, but two parameters will get posted into php,php should select non empty field and do some action! something like this.point me right direction. i think 'isset get' should not be used three times like that right?which statement to be used 'and' or 'or' statement.?
i know it's stupid question! i appreciate ur help.

```
if (isset($_GET['Email']) && !empty($_GET['Fax'])) {
    echo "fax is empty and Email = ".$_GET['Email'];
} elseif (isset($_GET['Fax']) && !empty($_GET['Email'])) {
    echo "email is empty and Fax = ".$_GET['Fax'];
} elseif (!empty($_GET['Fax']) && !empty($_GET['Email'])) {
    echo "Fax and email is empty";
} else {
    echo"empty";
}
```

Comment: so if i use all of them as empty, how can i use them in remaining program? u mean something like this..if(!empty($_GET['Fax'])){ $fax = $_GET['Fax']} @iStimple

Comment: thnx @iStimple well, it's for one parameter, how about three parameters, which statement should i use 'or' or 'and'?

Comment: still confusing,.i will work on it..thnks @iStimple

Answer (score 1):

Simpler version:

```
$email = isset($_GET['Email']) ? $_GET['Email'] : null;
$fax   = isset($_GET['Fax'])   ? $_GET['Fax']   : null;

if (empty($email)) {
  // email empty
}
if (empty($fax)) {
  // fax empty
}
```

Comment: ? $_GET['Email'] : null; can u tell me what does it mean? please! @hsZ

Comment: @user3923716 It's ternary operator. Manual: http://php.net//manual/pl/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: if both are empty, both if statements will get executed, how can i do something like if email is only empty(do something), how i can do that? @hsz